# How to use the same event for a number of controls?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

I have a lot of checkboxes inside a panel and I want to ask if exist any way to reproduce a event action in all the checkboxes without need to write the same for the 20 checkboxes:

```
  Private Sub C1CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles C1CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        C1CheckBox1.Text = "test"
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

I don't mean how to change the `text` property of all the checkboxes inside the `C1CheckBox1` event, what I mean is how to clone that event for all the checkboxes, if one of all checkboxes is clicked then reproduce the same event for all, it's a little difference (I think)

**UPDATE**:

Pseudocode:

```
sub event that affect to all my checkboxes in the panel
    If ANY checkbox_CheckedChange then
       ALL_the_other_Checkboxes.Checked = False
    end if
end sub
```

The difference that I'm trying to talking about is I ask if this is possible only writing one event or something like, to not write the same property change in the 20 other checkbox events.

Comment: Use the panel's Controls property to iterate the controls it contains.

Comment: thankyou for comment but sorry I don't understand what i need to do, which property of all?

Comment: can you put your checkboxes in a control array?

Comment: Well, post a realistic snippet and somebody will show you a better way.  Surely you don't want to set the Text property of all checkboxes to the same string?  What do you *really* want to do?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but you need to understand i'm not an expert, sorry for the bad snippet, i've updated my comment.

Comment: Beth, I don't learned how to do an array in VS, sorry, i need to learn more thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the same event by doing a comma separated list of controls and their event.

EG:

```
Private Sub C1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    Handles C1CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, C1CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, ... C1CheckBox50.CheckedChanged
        ...
        Do Action
        ....
    End Sub
```